# Xpath- that will retrieve if role is Active/Inactive

Tags: selenium, xpath, html-table

If you visit this link [login information already is there]

https://admin-demo.nopcommerce.com/Admin/CustomerRole/List

I am trying to capture what is the status of Free Shipping for Admin. I have tried a few things but cannon figure out a way to get it

**Trial 1:**

```
//table//thead//th[1]/../../..//tbody//tr//td[text()='Administrators']  >> role 


//table//thead//th[text()='Free shipping']/../../../../../..//tbody//tr//td[text()='Administrators']   >> service of role  *** I think from Admin i should traverse to service type
```

**Trial 2:**

```
public void changeRoleAs(String roleName , String roleType,  String isActive)
    {
        List<WebElement> allHeaders = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table//thead//th"));
        int colValue = allHeaders.indexOf(roleType)+1;
        String customLoc = "//td[text()='" + roleName + "']/..//td['" + colValue + "']/i";
       String vurrentValue =  driver.findElement(By.xpath(customLoc)).getAttribute("nop-value");
       if(!vurrentValue.equals(isActive))
       {

       }
```

What can be the xpath that I can use to check status, let's say something like below

Admin/FreeShipping./i getAttribute["nop-value"]

Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first find the rows by using their xpath and then can iterate through the rows to check if that row contains "Administrators", if yes then you can go to its child element using its xpath and then can find the `nop-value`.
You can do it like:

```
List<WebElement> elementList = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='dataTables_scrollBody']//tbody//tr"));
String nopValue="";
for(int i =0;i<elementList.size();i++){
    if(elementList.get(i).getText().contains("Administrators")){
        nopValue= elementList.get(i).findElement(By.xpath(".//i")).getAttribute("nop-value");
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Xpath for "Free Shipping" for "Administrators" would be `//tr[td[text()='Administrators']]/td[2]/i`

Then you get the attribute value like:

```java
String value =  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//tr[td[text()='Administrators']]/td[2]/i")).getAttribute("nop-value");
```

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to reference both the column `Free shipping` and row field `Free shipping` value then use below xpath to get the element and then use `getAttribute("nop-value")`.

```
//table[@id='customerroles-grid']//tr[./td[text()='Administrators']]/td[count(//table[@id='customerroles-grid']//th[contains(.,'Free shipping')]/preceding-sibling::*)+1]/i
```

Similar way you can do other value as well like

```
//table[@id='customerroles-grid']//tr[./td[text()='Administrators']]/td[count(//table[@id='customerroles-grid']//th[contains(.,'Active')]/preceding-sibling::*)+1]/i
```